# Uncaught InvalidStateError: Failed to execute 'send' on 'WebSocket'

Tags: javascript, websocket

> Uncaught InvalidStateError: Failed to execute 'send' on 'WebSocket': Still in CONNECTING state.(index):29 (anonymous function)

Código:

```
function smConnect() {
    ws = new WebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:1805/');
    delete ws.URL;

    ws.onopen = function(response) {
    };

    ws.onmessage = function(response) {
    };

    ws.onclose = function(response) {
    };

    ws.onerror = function(error) {
    };
}

smConnect();
ws.send('message', 'hi');
```

O que pode ser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segundo a mensagem retornada, você está tentando executar o método `send` **antes** mesmo de ter sido estabelecida a conexão.

Segundo a página do [w3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/CR-websockets-20111208/) sobre `WebSockets`:

> O método de send(data) transmite dados usando a conexão. Se o
>   atributo `readyState` está se conectando, deve lançar uma exceção
>   `InvalidStateError`.

O que você deve fazer é esperar que seja feita a conexão para então executar o método `send`.

Você pode implementar isto do seguinte modo ([créditos](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23913091/1608936)):

```js
function waitForSocketConnection(socket, callback){
        setTimeout(
            function(){
                if (socket.readyState === 1) {
                    if(callback !== undefined){
                        callback();
                    }
                    return;
                } else {
                    waitForSocketConnection(socket,callback);
                }
            }, 5);
    };
```

E utilizá-lo assim:

```js
waitForSocketConnection(ws, function() {
    ws.send('message', 'hi');
});
```

Ou simplesmente fazer isso no evento [`onOpen`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/CR-websockets-20111208/#dom-websocket-open):

```
ws.onopen = function(response) {
    ws.send('message', 'hi');
};
```

Comment: O método do timer cheira a gambiarra, prefiro o `onopen`.