# Reconectar Websocket após perda de conexão

Tags: javascript, websocket

Eu uso este código para me conectar ao meu servidor com *WebSockets*:

```js
(function(nameSpace) {
  function createMethod(method, options, stateCallback) {
    var that = this;
    this[method] = function() {
      if (stateCallback && stateCallback.apply) {
        stateCallback(method);
      }
      console.info(method);
      if (options[method] && options[method].apply) {
        options[method].apply(that, arguments);
      }
    };
  }

  function SocketWrapper(options) {
    var ws,
      events = ['onopen', 'onmessage', 'onclose', 'onerror'],
      i, len, prop = {
        opened: false,
        closed: false,
        error: false
      },
      method;

    if (typeof options === 'undefined' || !options) {
      throw 'ArgumentException: please add default constructor options';
    }

    this.queue = [];

    this.onEventTrigger = function(eventName) {
      var i, len;
      if (eventName === 'onopen') {
        prop.opened = true;
        prop.closed = false;
        // openend send queue
        if (this.queue.length > 0) {
          for (i = this.queue.length; --i >= 0;) {
            this.send.apply(this, this.queue[0]);
            this.queue.splice(0, 1);
          }
        }
      }
      if (eventName === 'onerror') {
        prop.error = true;
      }
      if (eventName === 'onclosed') {
        prop.opened = false;
        prop.closed = true;
      }
    };

    this.init = function() {
      var cb = this.onEventTrigger.bind(this);
      ws = new WebSocket(options.url);

      for (i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
        method = events[i];
        createMethod.apply(ws, [method, options, cb]);
      }
    };

    this.send = function() {
      if (prop.closed) {
        throw 'InvalidOperation: Cannot send messages to a closed Websocket!';
      }
      if (!prop.opened) {
        this.queue.push(arguments);
      } else {
        ws.send.apply(ws, arguments);
      }
    };

    this.init();
    return this;
  }

  window.SocketWrapper = SocketWrapper;
}(window));

var socket = new window.SocketWrapper({
  url: 'ws://127.0.0.1:1805',
  onopen: function() {
    this.send('message', 'hi');
  },
  onmessage: function() {
    console.log(arguments);
  },
  onclose: function() {
    socket = null;
  },
  onerror: function() {
    console.log('error occured, oh no!');
    console.error(arguments);
  }
});
socket.send('i am message send to soon, but since i check the state of the ws object, i will be queued and send when appropriate');
```

Esse código me cai bem, foi a solução que eu encontrei pro meu caso, porém eu queria que ele se reconectasse assim que a conexão fosse perdida, ele ficasse tentando reconectar até conseguir..não sei muito como adaptar porque não é meu, como proceder?

Comment: Diferente dessa sua outra [pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/55082/6454), aqui você deve verificar isso no evento [**Onclose**](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/CR-websockets-20111208/#dom-websocket-close).

Comment: @Qmechanic73 sim isso eu sei, mas como força-lo a refazer a conexao apartir dai?

Comment: Tenho uma ideia, mas tenho como testar, não sei se é viável também, posso arriscar uma resposta. =/

Comment: @Qmechanic73 qualquer idéia vale uma resposta haha

Comment: Dessa linha(`var socket = new window.SocketWrapper({`) para baixo delete e tente implementar esse [**código**](http://pastebin.com/4GpmxC5E), não cheguei a testar, veja se algo ocorre. =)

Comment: @Qmechanic73 funcionou, bela idéia! Vou ficar testando, obrigado!!

Comment: @Qmechanic73 testei testei e funciona corretamente, obrigado dnv =)

Comment: Postei a resposta. Eu sem querer usei `return socket = new window.SocketWrapper..` no início da função, retire o `socket = `.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quando a conexão é perdida o evento [`onclose`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/CR-websockets-20111208/#dom-websocket-closed) é acionado, para fazer a reconexão você deve trabalhar em cima desse evento.

Um modo que você pode utilizar para conectar novamente é por meio da função [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout), ela vai executar uma ação a cada *n* segundos.

Ao invés declarar a variável `socket` com todo aquele código, faça isso numa função:

```
function CreateSocketWrapper(){
    return new window.SocketWrapper({
      url: 'ws://127.0.0.1:1805',
      onopen: function() {
        this.send('message', 'hi');
      },
      onmessage: function() {
        console.log(arguments);
      },
      onclose: function() {
        setTimeout(function(){CreateSocketWrapper()}, 5000); // 5 segundos
      },
      onerror: function() {
        console.log('error occured, oh no!');
        console.error(arguments);
      }
    });
}
```

E para usá-la:

```
var socket = CreateSocketWrapper();
socket.send('i am message send to soon, but since i check the state of...');
```